# How to check if an element exists inside the <body>?

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I need to verify if an element is present. I used toBeTruthy() and it worked fine. I wanted to see if it is really checking for the element so I used toBeFalsy() to see if it fails the test. It didn't. Because this element is in the `<style>` inside the `<head>`. How can I verify if it is visible inside the `<body>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Narrowing the search like this should be easy depending on the locator you are using.

Using CSS: `element(by.css('body original_locator'))`

Using Xpath: `(by.xpath('//body//original_locator'))`

Alternatively you could chain the elements if you are using one of the other locator strategies like className: `element(by.css('body')).element(by.className('orginal_locator))'`

Both of these approaches are stating that you only want elements which are descendants of `body`

Answer (score 1):

if you want to check if the element exists you should go with

```
expect(
  await element(by.css('your locator')).isPresent()
).toBe(true)
```

if you want to make sure it is not only present but also visible then use

```
expect(
  await element(by.css('your locator')).isDisplayed()
).toBe(true)
```

If your problem is in locating the element, then use either of these

CSS: `body > yourElement`, `>` in this case indicates immediate child of body

XPath: `//body/yourElement`. If you use `/` instead of `//` after `body`, this indicates that you're looking for immediate child of body element